# How to use zIndex on textField, so i can move to other textField when i press next in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium, z-index, textfield

does anyone know how to do that? i have this code :

```
var txtOne = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:50,
    zIndex:1
});

var txtTwo = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:100
});

var txtThree = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:150,
    zIndex:2
});
```

all i want is to jump from txtOne to txtThree without go to txtTwo..

I try to use zIndex but it not works for me..

any idea?? thanks

Comment: using the Z index seems like a bad idea to begin with. that isn't what it was intended for.

Comment: @timothy Groote: Do you have other idea how to do that?

Comment: Not sure if my idea is the way to go with either, but it should work. i posted an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

you could put them into an array, and assign them event handlers for their return functions like this:

```
var textFields = [txtOne, txtTwo, txtThree];

for(vat i=0; i < textFields.length; i++)
{
    //make the last text field jump to the first one when returning
    if(i == textFields.length-1)
    {
        textFields [i].addEventListener('return', function(e)
        {
            textFields[0].focus();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //jump to the next text fields when returning
        textFields [i].addEventListener('return', function(e)
        {
            textFields[i+1].focus();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Timothy Groote.. i will try that.. but still wondering what is the function of zIndex properties on textfield..

Comment: A textfield probably has that property because it inherits from titanium's default view object, which has a z-index.
By default, z-index is not set, but if you set it you can manually determine which items will be rendered in front of, or behind others.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-zIndex

Comment: Thanks for your information Timothy.. i will try your suggestion first.. :)